# React switching between components or hiding and transitions

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to set up the general page rendering of an app and need help/advice as a newbie. The code below allows me to include components base on a state I can change by clicking on a button. I am not sure if this is the best way to do this but when I click on my buttons they include the components needed.

Now when I click on them the other pages just disappear and show up without any transition. How would I fade out a little slower or transition better to the next component?

My app.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//Adding Components
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import Game from "./Components/Game";
import Myp from "./Components/Myp";
import Tutorial from "./Components/Tutorial";
//Import Styles
import "./styles/app.scss";

function App() {
  const [pageStatus, setPageStatus] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <section>
        {(() => {
          switch (pageStatus) {
            case 1:
              return (
                <Game pageStatus={pageStatus} setPageStatus={setPageStatus} />
              );
            case 2:
              return (
                <Tutorial
                  pageStatus={pageStatus}
                  setPageStatus={setPageStatus}
                />
              );
            case 3:
              return (
                <Myp pageStatus={pageStatus} setPageStatus={setPageStatus} />
              );
            default:
              return (
                <Home pageStatus={pageStatus} setPageStatus={setPageStatus} />
              );
          }
        })()}
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Home.js

```
import React from "react";
//Import Images or Logos
import logo from "../icons/EduLogo.ico";

const Home = ({ setPageStatus, pageStatus }) => {
  return (
    <div className="home">
        <div className="head">
          <h1>EduMemory</h1>
          <img alt="EduMemory logo" src={logo}></img>
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => setPageStatus(1)}>Play</button>
        <button onClick={() => setPageStatus(2)}>How To Play</button>
        <button onClick={() => setPageStatus(3)}>Tom's MYP</button>
      </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found this library which is live and works very well https://github.com/dennismorello/react-awesome-reveal

---

Also I made little sample for you hope it will work for you.
It's custom (No library).
Link for DEMO is here https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-gould-rjczp

Lets say you have this animation from 0 opacity to 100.
When you render component this class automatically will renew itself and animation will start from the beginning.

```
.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn ease 3s;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Link, Route, Switch, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import Secondary from "./secondary";
class app extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <Router>
          <Link to="/">Main</Link> | <Link to="/secondary">Secondary</Link>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact>
              <div className="fade-in">
                <div>Main</div>
              </div>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/secondary">
              <Secondary />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default app;
```

Secondary.js

```
import React from "react";

export default function Secondary() {
  return <div className="fade-in">Secondary</div>;
}
```

This is may be already dead library but if you want you can use react-reveal for transition effects. It's very easy to use, just wrap your content inside `<Fade></Fade>` tags

```
import React from "react";
//Import Images or Logos
import logo from "../icons/EduLogo.ico";
import Fade from 'react-reveal/Fade';

const Home = ({ setPageStatus, pageStatus }) => {
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <Fade> //here goes react-reveal/fade
        <div className="head">
          <h1>EduMemory</h1>
          <img alt="EduMemory logo" src={logo}></img>
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => setPageStatus(1)}>Play</button>
        <button onClick={() => setPageStatus(2)}>How To Play</button>
        <button onClick={() => setPageStatus(3)}>Tom's MYP</button>
      </Fade>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

Link here https://www.react-reveal.com/examples/common/Fade

Comment: Thanks Tiffany. it looks slick but is [showing as a dead library](https://github.com/rnosov/react-reveal/issues/86). Looks like it hasn't been updated in over 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

You could try AOS library.
You just wrap the component in whatever and add what fade effect you want!
Here's how it looks: https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/
Github: https://github.com/michalsnik/aos

Comment: Nice tto but over 2 years since there has been an update. Looking for a maintained library. thx tho :-)